# How to compare contents of two directoriers in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, directory, comparison, zsh

Lets say there are two dirs

```
/path1 and /path2
```

for example

```
/path1/bin
/path1/lib
/path1/...

/path2/bin
/path2/lib
/path2/...
```

And one needs to know **if they are identical by contents (names of files and content of files) and if not have differences listed**.

How to do this in Linux?
Is there some Bash/Zsh command for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The diff command can show all the differences between two directories:
`diff -qr /path1 /path2`

Comment: what's "a" and "b"? you'd also want `-r`

Answer (score 3):

Someone suggested this already but deleted their answer, not sure why. Try using `rsync`:

```
rsync -avni /path1/ /path2
```

This program will normally sync two folders, but with -n it will do a dry-run instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this script for such a task:

```
diff <(cd "$dir1"; find . -type f -printf "%p %s\n" | sort) \
     <(cd "$dir2"; find . -type f -printf "%p %s\n" | sort)
```

Feel free to adjust the script in the `<(...)` part to your specific needs.  This version uses `find` to print the directory contents by printing the paths and the sizes of the files it found therein.  Other things are possible of course.